# DiscordJS bot connecting to vocal channel but music is not playing

Tags: discord.js, ytdl

I try to make a discord bot with DiscordJS, but I am unable to make it playing music. It connects to the vocal channel, send the informations of the music, but it's not playing the music. I have no error. Here is my code :

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
var index = require('../index')
const {
    Discord,
    MessageEmbed
} = require("discord.js");
const values = require('../values.json');
const config = require('../config.json');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const {
    AudioPlayerStatus,
    StreamType,
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource,
    joinVoiceChannel,
} = require('@discordjs/voice');

/**
 *
 * @param {Discord.Client} bot
 * @param {Discord.Message} message
 */

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('play')
        .setDescription('Permet de lancer le son d\'une vidéo (en général une musique) à partir d\'un lien ou d\'un titre')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('video').setDescription('Lien ou titre de la vidéo').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const video = interaction.options.getString('video');
        if (maintenance) { await interaction.reply({ content: values.maintenancemessage, ephemeral: true }); return; }
        await interaction.deferReply();
        const result = await sendMusic(interaction.user, video, interaction);
        await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [result] });
    },
};

async function sendMusic(user, video, interaction) {
    let userId = user.id.toString().replace(/[\\<>@#&!]/g, "");
    const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(video);
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
        channelId: interaction.client.guilds.cache.get(config.guildId).members.cache.get(userId).voice.channel.id,
        guildId: config.guildId,
        adapterCreator: interaction.client.guilds.cache.get(config.guildId).voiceAdapterCreator
    })
    var stream = ytdl(video, {highWaterMark: 1 << 25,filter: 'audioonly'})
    //playMusic(voiceConnection, interaction.client.guilds.cache.get(config.guildId).members.cache.get(userId).voice.channel, stream)
    const player = createAudioPlayer();
    connection.subscribe(player)
    const resource = createAudioResource(stream, {inputType: StreamType.Opus});
    player.play(resource)
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ffff00')
            .setTitle(":guitar: Lancement d'une musique")
            .setDescription("Je joue maintenant : " + songInfo.videoDetails.title)
            .setAuthor(user.username, user.avatarURL({
                size: 1024,
                dynamic: true
            }))
            .setThumbnail(songInfo.videoDetails.thumbnails[1].url)
            .setFooter("Fonctionnalité expérimentale, en cas de bug, se référer au bot annexe")
        return resolve(embed);
    });
}
```

I hope you'll be able to help me ! Thanks :)

Comment: Is the bot self-deafened?

Comment: Yes, it is @MrMythical

Comment: Okay so I'll add the part of code to tell him to not self deaf/mute but anyway, I changed the module. I was using ytdl and I'm now using play-dl and it seems to work. Thank you very much for your time !

It's curious because I already tried this before but it didn't work first time.